# Service for storing PCI sensitive data

Tags: security, hosting, pci-dss

I'm building a web application that handles sensitive PCI data (banking numbers, CC, SSNs, etc).  Does anyone know of the best services out there to handle this data.  I've looked into Rackspace and their PCI solution seems a little overkill for what I need as I mainly just need the database secured and there are really only a few pages that need to be compliant and won't receive a relatively large amount of traffic.

Note:  A lot of the webpages don't require this data and receive higher load volume and I am planning on hosting these pages on the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [tokenization service](http://www.google.com/search?q=tokenization+service). A google search brings up plenty of alternatives.